# Detect Arduino port in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, usb, arduino

I'm trying to open each port and send `<mccon>` serially, for which my microcontroller will respond `<connected>\n` after which the C# code must exit the for each loop.

I'm having a problem at the `serialPort.PortName = str;` line. After two iterations, it does not continue further.

I tried doing this manually too. I made a drop down and selected ports one by one. After the second port, it does not allow to change the serial Port. But in case I select within two tries, it works fine.

I know OOP in C++. But I'm new to C#. I'm not sure why the loop fails.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    send_button.Enabled = false;

    //Availabe COM ports
    SerialPort tmp;
    foreach(string str in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        tmp = new SerialPort(str);
        if (tmp.IsOpen == false)
        {
            serialPort.PortName = str;

            try
            {
                //Open serial port
                serialPort.Open();
                serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort.WriteTimeout = 10;
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10;
                serialPort.Write("<mccon>");
                readtxt.Text = serialPort.ReadTo("\n");
                if (readtxt.Text == "<connected>")
                {
                    send_button.Enabled = true;
                    port_combobox.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    serialPort.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `serialPort` defined as? Do you mean `tmp`? Is it a member variable?

Comment: @DavidHope `serialPort` is defined in Form1.Designer.cs as `SerialPort`. Maybe I should not use the `tmp` instead use `serialPort` itself. Both are `SerialPort` types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have multiple serial ports, but when I compiled and executed your code, I noticed that you are not closing the serial port if it errors during the read. I suggest you modify your code as follows:

```
        SerialPort tmp;
        foreach (string str in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            tmp = new SerialPort(str);
            if (tmp.IsOpen == false)
            {

                serialPort.PortName = str;

                try
                {
                    //open serial port
                    serialPort.Open();
                    serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                    serialPort.WriteTimeout = 10;
                    serialPort.ReadTimeout = 10;
                    serialPort.Write("<mccon>");
                    String s = serialPort.ReadTo("\n");
                    if (s == "<connected>")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serialPort.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    serialPort.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure the effect on changing the port name while it's open, but it could well cause the issues you are seeing.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Learnt something new. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHope I tried implementing your code with a slight change. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33853009/4794952) is the problem I am facing please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Could you execute this code and return what it shows? It might show some information about the Arduino port which you can then use for the serialport.

Add a reference to `System.Management` and also add the using, and then try the code:

```
using System.Management;

try
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                                     "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        if (queryObj["Caption"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("ARDUINO"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(queryObj["Caption"]);
            foreach (PropertyData pd in queryObj.Properties) { Console.WriteLine(pd.Name + " : " + pd.Value); }
        }
    }
}
catch (ManagementException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Actually, that does work. Since the description of my board will contain "Arduino". But, you can't use this method as it is too general. Any other Arduino board connected to the same system may be selected in the process done by this code. So the best way is to communicate and check for a unique response.

Comment: @NeilMartin ah ok, was just looking through other similar questions and they mentioned wmi and I thought it might help you.