# Find which port Arduino is connected

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, arduino

I know how to list the available Serial Ports but whow can I find the right COM port everytime I connect my Arduino? COM Port should be printed like `MessageBox.Show(COMport);`

I want to read/write Arduino data in a Visual C# application.

[[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857028/2208810) didn't work for me]

Comment: maybe try to sequentialy write to all serial ports open. (the risk is to talk to something else) Maybe there is a device identification available

Answer (score 3):

Open Device manager, expand "Ports (COM & LPT)". Plug in the Arduino USB connection, a new COM port shows up with name Arduino UNO (COMxx). This is on my machine as I have an Arduino UNO.

You can find this string using WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation). I am using the method below in a class, and has COMports as a public List

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

 public void getCOMportsValues()
    {
        try
        {
            if (COMports.Count > 0) COMports.Clear(); // COMports is a List<string>

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                string s = queryObj["Name"] as string;
                if (s.Contains("(COM"))
                    COMports.Add(s);
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying WMI data: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have `using System.Management;` but it says 'ManagementObjectSearcher' and 'ManagementException' could not be found. COMports is a listBox? `COMports.Count > 0` is not accepted also

Comment: COMports is a List<string> You have to declare it before use. I am using WPF, maybe WinForms use other assemblies? Sorry cannot help you there. Try a google search WMI+C#+WinForms maybe? ManagementObjectSearcher at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can program your Arduino to send a specific pattern through serial and your C# listen to all COM ports, looking for the specific pattern.

Answer (score -2):

To elaborate, the com ports are named: COM1, COM2, COM3, etc.

So, coding a loop that opens each COMn and if the open succeeds send a serial stream and see if you get the correct response.

Finally, in C you can `sprintf(port_name, "COM%d", port_nr);` to generate the port names for open.

Comment: There can be things plugged in to those serial ports.  This is not good advice to just transmit data to unknown devices and see what happens.

Comment: @jackccoleman, it is doubtful that if a device receives "hi" that it will decide to erase all of its data.