# ArgumentOutOfRangeException on SerialPort.ReadTo()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port, parallel.foreach

My code indeterminately throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required.` when invoking the `ReadTo()` method of the `SerialPort` class:

```
public static void RetrieveCOMReadings(List<SuperSerialPort> ports)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(ports, 
        port => port.Write(port.ReadCommand));

    Parallel.ForEach(ports,
        port =>
        {
            try
            {
                // this is the offending line.
                string readto = port.ReadTo(port.TerminationCharacter);

                port.ResponseData = port.DataToMatch.Match(readto).Value;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                port.ResponseData = null;
            }
        });
}
```

`SuperSerialPort` is an extension of the `SerialPort` class, primarily to hold information required for communications specific to each device on the port.
A port always has the `TerminationCharacter` defined;
Most of the time it's a newline character:

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening.
If the ReadTo fails to find the character(s) specified in the input buffer, shouldn't it just timeout and return nothing?

---

The StackTrace is pointing to an offending function in the mscorlib, in the definition of the SerialPort class:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: byteCount
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=byteCount
  StackTrace:
       at System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetMaxCharCount(Int32 byteCount)
  InnerException:
```

I followed it and here's what I found:

```
private int ReadBufferIntoChars(char[] buffer, int offset, int count, bool countMultiByteCharsAsOne)
{
    Debug.Assert(count != 0, "Count should never be zero.  We will probably see bugs further down if count is 0.");

    int bytesToRead = Math.Min(count, CachedBytesToRead);

    // There are lots of checks to determine if this really is a single byte encoding with no
    // funky fallbacks that would make it not single byte
    DecoderReplacementFallback fallback = encoding.DecoderFallback as DecoderReplacementFallback;
    ----> THIS LINE 
    if (encoding.IsSingleByte && encoding.GetMaxCharCount(bytesToRead) == bytesToRead && 
        fallback != null && fallback.MaxCharCount == 1)
    {   
        // kill ASCII/ANSI encoding easily.
        // read at least one and at most *count* characters
        decoder.GetChars(inBuffer, readPos, bytesToRead, buffer, offset);
```

`bytesToRead` is getting assigned a negative number because `CachedBytesToRead` is negative. The inline comments specify that `CachedBytesToRead` can never be negative, yet it's clearly the case:

```
    private int readPos = 0;    // position of next byte to read in the read buffer.  readPos <= readLen
    private int readLen = 0;    // position of first unreadable byte => CachedBytesToRead is the number of readable bytes left.

    private int CachedBytesToRead {
        get {
            return readLen - readPos;
        }
```

Anyone have any rational explanation for why this is happening?
I don't believe I'm doing anything illegal in terms of reading/writing/accessing the SerialPorts.
This gets thrown constantly, with no good way to reproduce it.
There's bytes available on the input buffer, here you can see the state of some of the key properties when it breaks (readLen, readPos, BytesToRead, CachedBytesToRead):

[image]

Am I doing something glaringly wrong?

---

EDIT: A picture showing that the same port isn't being asynchronously accessed from the loop: [image]

Comment: I have zero experience in working with the serial port, so forgive me: Do you have any idea where you are in the stream when the error occurs?  To me it appears that you are running into the error right at the start or "end" of a stream where your position is -1 and the length is zero.  In other words, readPos is zero and the length is -1? That causes CachedBytesToRead to be negative. That probably doesn't help you?

Comment: @rune711 You can see in the last screenshot that `readPos` is 5 and `readLen` is 2. That still ends up with `CachedBytesToRead` being -3. You would think that if `CachedBytesToRead` was less than `bytesToRead` that it would try to read another chunk from the port.

Comment: readLen and readPos are private members of the SerialPort implementation in mscorlib.dll. I have no control over them. I included the blurb about them because it demonstrates why the exception is being thrown, but not _why_ it's happening, to which I have no idea. All I'm doing is calling ReadTo(NewLine) on a port after writing some data to it in order to capture it's response. I know a priori how the data is terminated.

Comment: How much data is expected in between the TerminationCharacters ? You could be overflowing an internal integer of some size.

Comment: It varies, but for the device I've been using to test this code, 26 bytes. I wouldn't imagine I could be overflowing anything since I call Read after every Write.

Comment: Is it possible that `ports` contains the same port more than once, and so your `Parallel.ForEach` reads from the same port in parallel?

Comment: Nope. I only enumerate over each Port connected to the system one time to determine if it's a device I'm interested in. In fact, I'm using only one connected Port at the moment to try and diagnose the root of this exception (system wide, not just in the scope of my program)

Comment: Which encoder is the SerialPort using? Can/did you try the ASCIIEncoding?

Comment: @rene Uses ASCII by default. Confirmed by the documentation: _By default, SerialPort uses ASCIIEncoding to encode the characters. ASCIIEncoding encodes all characters greater than 127 as (char)63 or '?'._ It bombs out at System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetMaxCharCount(Int32 byteCount), but uses "encoder" as the object that makes the call. In the prototype of the library, encoder is defined as: _private Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII; // ASCII is default encoding for modem communication, etc._

Comment: You are Writing and Reading on seperate threads, aren't you? Can you synchronize that?

Comment: @rene I'm sure some of the reads and writes are kicked off in separate threads. Is my data not coherent? I was under the impression my Read loop wouldn't execute till all my Writes propagated. Should I be handling this a different way?

Comment: I realized that this morning. So I would also assume that the writes have finished before the reads start. I posted my comments due to he fact that ILSPY showed me that the SerialPort used the sqme buffer for both reading and writing. Having a race condition there would certainly corrupt that internal buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is technically possible, in general a common issue with .NET classes that are not thread-safe.  The SerialPort class is not, there's no practical case where it *needs* to be thread-safe.

The rough diagnostic is that two separate threads are calling ReadTo() on the same SerialPort object concurrently.  A standard threading race condition will occur in the code that updates the *readPos* variable.  Both threads have copied the same data from the buffer and each increment readPos.  In effect advancing readPos too far by double the amount.  Kaboom when the next call occurs with readPos larger than readLen, producing a negative value for the number of available bytes in the buffer.

The simple explanation is that your `List<SuperSerialPort>` collection contains the same port more than once.  The Parallel.ForEach() statement triggers the race.  Works just fine for a while, until two threads execute the decoder.GetChars() method simultaneously and both arrive at the next statement:

```
   readPos += bytesToRead;
```

Best way to test the hypothesis is to add code that ensures that the list does contain the same port more than once.  Roughly:

```
#if DEBUG
        for (int ix = 0; ix < ports.Count - 1; ++ix)
            for (int jx = ix + 1; jx < ports.Count; ++jx)
                if (ports[ix].PortName == ports[jx].PortName)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Port used more than once");
#endif
```

A second explanation is that your method is being calling by more than one thread.  That can't work, your method isn't thread-safe.  Short from protecting it with a lock, making sure that only one thread ever calls it is the logical fix.

Comment: I copied my list of ports to a static object so I could inspect the contents when the code breaks in the parallel loop. No indication of a reused port, and no exceptions generated from your code. See my edit for a picture that shows what I mean. Is this an invalid way of testing it? The picture doesn't show but I am indeed on the debug configuration.

Comment: Next thing to consider is that RetrieveCOMReadings() is being called by more than one thread.  Add `Debug.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);`

Comment: Not entirely unrelated, this is a question I had asked before that is the motivation behind accessing the serial ports asynchronously. Reading multiple serial ports on the UI thread was killing the responsiveness. Is there a better way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056306/reliably-detecting-presence-of-external-hardware

Comment: The Thread IDs are different, but often repeated. I'm spawning off RetrieveCOMReadings() as a separate Task, and calling it at some variable interval. Is this likely my problem? I wonder if a ReadTo is timing out as the next call comes in.

Comment: That doesn't sound good, you'll need to ensure that the method can never run concurrently.  Do add an explicitly lock.  No, a timeout can never cause this problem.

Comment: I placed a lock on the list of ports surrounding the reads and it appears to have remedied the problem. Is my thinking correct? If you want to update your answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: It is a workaround, not a fix.  Nothing that pretty about having a thread block on a lock for a long time.  It is not very clear to me why you can't call this method more reliably.

Comment: I need to poll x number of devices connected via individual COM ports, the theoretical maximum being however many the system can handle. Polling more than 1 or 2 on the UI thread faster than ~100ms really bogs down the UI, so instead kick it off into a thread. If I wait on said thread, it blocks the UI thread anyway. I'm a beginner to threading, so I'm not pretending that what I'm doing is right. More than open to suggestions as per the question and other comments.

Comment: Well, don't poll.  The SerialPort.DataReceived event already runs on a worker thread, stops you from having to add your own threading.  Calling ReadTo or ReadLine in the event handler is fine.  Also avoids the current ugliness of the method only being able to complete when *all* of the devices send something back.  In itself a good way to get re-entrancy.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused because you are setting a termination character and using this character for readto. Instead try to use ReadLine or remove the termination character.

Comment: Ironically, the ReadLine function is a one liner and defined as: *return ReadTo(NewLine);* Care to guess the definition of NewLine?: *private const string defaultNewLine = "\n";* http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/SerialPort.cs

Comment: Ok, then the only thing i can tell you is to use the binary asynchronous events, I use a lot the serial ports with c# to comunícate with microcontrollers and using the binary events/functions never had a problem, but of course is more complicated to handle.

Comment: I appreciate the input, not every data stream is terminated by a NewLine, however. I'm not sure I follow your second suggestion; What are the binary asynchronous events? Do you mean managing my own SerialStreams?

Comment: Hook to datareceived event, then inside read BytesToRead (property of serialport) bytes with Read function  store it into a buffer and process it